# how to correctly send CMFCMenuButton selected ID to the message map?

Tags: c++, menu, mfc, dialog, cmfcmenubutton

firstly let me describe what I have:
**scenario:** `CMFCMenuButton`, loaded with a `CMenu`, in a dialog 
**test:** click on an item of the menu
**result:** the message map will get the ID of the `CMFCMenuButton` and not the ID of the menu

**how to get the actual menu ID clicked:** use `CMFCMenuButton::m_nMenuResult`
The idea is that I want to have menu items and buttons in this dialog, and there would be buttons that share IDs with the menu items.
So in the handler that I've created for the menu button I can get that `m_nMenuResult` and send it to the dialog or do whatever I want, but that doesn't seem to be how the `CMFCMenuButton` should work. What is the correct way of doing it?

### Code

Here follows an example on how you can reproduce this.

I've used `ON_COMMAND_RANGE` also with `IDC_MFCMENUBUTTON1` just to reuse the code for the OnMenu function

```c++
void CRepositionDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_MFCMENUBUTTON1, m_cmfcMenuButton);
}


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CRepositionDlg, CDialog)
    ON_COMMAND_RANGE(IDC_MFCMENUBUTTON1,IDC_MFCMENUBUTTON1,OnMenu)

    ON_COMMAND_RANGE(IDC_MENU1, IDC_MENU11, OnMenu)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// CRepositionDlg message handlers

afx_msg void CRepositionDlg::OnMenu(UINT nID)
{
    CString csMessage;
    csMessage.Format(L"OnMenu(%d)",nID);
    AfxMessageBox(csMessage);
    if(nID == IDC_MFCMENUBUTTON1)
    {
        OnMenu(m_cmfcMenuButton.m_nMenuResult);
    }
}


BOOL CRepositionDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();

    // TODO:  Add extra initialization here

    CMenu* pMenu = new CMenu;
    pMenu->CreatePopupMenu();
    for(int i = IDC_MENU1; i <= IDC_MENU11; i++)
    {
        CString csMenu;
        csMenu.Format(L"menu %d",i);
        pMenu->AppendMenuW(MF_STRING,i,csMenu);
    }
    m_cmfcMenuButton.m_hMenu = pMenu->GetSafeHmenu();
    return TRUE;  // return TRUE unless you set the focus to a control
    // EXCEPTION: OCX Property Pages should return FALSE
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code you're using?  I think I understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: @rrirower thanks for your comment, I've added some code, check it out.

Comment: I've read your code.  What is it that you want the button and menu items to do exactly?  It sounds like you want to re-use resource IDs.  I don't quite understand why you would want that.

Comment: @rrirower I want that when I click on a menu item in the CMFCMenuButton I get a message that is IDC_MENU1 till IDC_MENU11 and not IDC_MFCMENUBUTTON1. because now any action done on the button will have the ID IDC_MFCMENUBUTTON1 and not the ID that is in the clicked menu

Comment: If you code a handler for _BN_CLICKED_ for the menu button, it will respond with 0 for m_nMenuResult if the click is on the button, or, m_nMenuResult will contain the Id of the menu item selected.  If that's not what you wanted, I think you're fighting against the way the button works.  Your only  other option would be to create your own class to represent a menu button and add the behavior you want.

Comment: @rrirower I was not sure how the button worked, but found strange that I didn't get the menu's ID in the message map. so I guess the button has this different behaviour than normal menus. copy your comment to an answer so I can mark it. thanks for your time =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you code a handler for [BN_CLICKED](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761825(v=vs.85).aspx) for the menu button, it will respond with 0 for *m_nMenuResult* if the click is on the button, or, *m_nMenuResult* will contain the ID of the menu item selected. If that's not what you wanted, I think you're fighting against the way the button works. Your only other option would be to create your own class to represent a menu button and add the behavior you want.